# JQuery animate() & inconsistency in Chrome and Firefox

Tags: firefox, jquery-animate

I am doing a jQuery animation of 3 boxes, the effect is like the jsfiddle link below:

#### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/monkichik/zrbt7o0n/embedded/result/)

Basically when clicked on each color box the corresponding box will enlarge to width 100% taking up all width. And when clicking close (yes, it is not functioning well) the box will shrink back to its original position.

What I encountered now is

1. When enlarging the pink or the blue box, sometimes the yellow box on RHS will jump to next row (but just a very quick jump, i dunno why). It happens only in Chrome, looks perfect in Firefox.[image]
2. When clicking the close button, it will trigger the yellow box to
   enlarge (supposed it has taken up 0% of width? Why the bind click
   still works?

Could someone advise how I should solve these and is there a better way for me to achieve the same results?

HTML

```
<div class="animateWrap">
<div id="btn_howtojoin" class="btn_group">
    <div class="btn_close"></div>
    <div class="content">Content</div>
</div>
<div id="btn_judgecriteria" class="btn_group">
    <div class="btn_close"></div>
    <div class="content">Content</div>
</div>
<div id="btn_prizeinfo" class="btn_group">
    <div class="btn_close">Close</div>
    <div class="content">Content</div>
</div>
<div class="clear00"></div>
```

JS

```
$(function () {


$('#btn_judgecriteria').bind('click', function () {
    $(this).animate({
        width: "100%"
    }, function () {
        $(this).animate({
            height: "400px"
        });
        $('.btn_close').show();
    });
    $('#btn_prizeinfo').animate({
        width: "0%"
    });
    $('#btn_howtojoin').animate({
        width: "0%"
    });

});

$('#btn_howtojoin').bind('click', function () {

    $(this).animate({
        width: "100%"
    }, function () {

        $(this).animate({

            height: "400px"
        });


        $(this).find('.content').animate({
            top: "40px"
        });

        $('.btn_close').show();

    });

    $('#btn_prizeinfo').animate({
        width: "0%"
    });
    $('#btn_judgecriteria').animate({
        width: "0%"
    });

});


$('#btn_prizeinfo').bind('click', function () {

    $(this).animate({
        width: "100%"
    }, function () {

        $(this).animate({
            height: "400px"
        });

        $('.btn_close').show();

    });

    $('#btn_howtojoin').animate({
        width: "0%"
    });
    $('#btn_judgecriteria').animate({
        width: "0%"
    });

});

$('.btn_close').bind('click', function () {
    $('.btn_group').animate({
        width: "33.333%",
        height: "220px"
    });

    $('.btn_group .content').hide();

    $('.btn_close').hide();
});
});
```

CSS

```
.btn_group {
    width: 33.3%;
    height: 220px;
    float: left;
    cursor: pointer;
    position:relative;
}

#btn_howtojoin {
    background: #fcb2b2 ;
    width: 33.4%;
}

#btn_judgecriteria {
    background: #7acccb ;
}
#btn_prizeinfo {
    background: #f1c348;
}

.btn_group .content {
    position:absolute;
    top:-400px;
    left:40px;
}
.btn_close {
    position:absolute;
    top:20px;
    right:20px;
    color:#FFF;
    width: 40px;
    height:62px;
    display:none;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem 1 maybe due to rounding up calculation of 33.333% which make the total width of 3 container slightly larger than 100%. Changing them to pixel might help.

Problem 2 is due to event bubbling, it will trigger click event of .btn_group after .btn_close 
Add event.stopPropagation(); will help solving this.

```
 $('.btn_close').bind('click', function () {
        $('.btn_group').animate({
            width: "33.333%",
            height: "220px"
        });

        $('.btn_group .content').hide();

        $('.btn_close').hide();
        event.stopPropagation();
  });
```